# impresion de textarea en html

Tags: html, sql, textarea

Buen día comunidad.
Necesito ayuda con textarea.
En mi formulario puedo editar y se imprime bien el textarea, pero cuando quiero usar lo que se guardo en la base de datos me sale el texto de corrido

por ejemplo, escribo en el textarea

```
- Carne
- Mayonesa
- Azucar
```

Lo guardo y lo vuelvo a imprimir en un textarea de editar y se ve igual.

Pero si lo imprimo en html lo guardado en la base de datos me lo imprime asi

```
- Carne- Mayonesa- Azucar"
```

¿Cómo podría imprimir mi consulta en html que se vea asi como en el textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que `texarea` interpreta los saltos de línea como `\n`, y al darle guardar en la base de datos se almacenan de la misma manera. Por eso al traerlos otra vez a un campo `textarea` se ve bien.
Pero en el caso de pintar el contenido en la página, HTML no interpreta los `\n` y por eso sale todo en una línea.

Para resolverlo solo hay que convertir `\n` a `<br />` y la forma dependerá de qué lenguaje estás usando para imprimir el texto traído de la Base de Datos en el HTML. ¿PHP, Javascript?
Por ejemplo, PHP tiene una [función incorporada](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php) para eso:

```php
<div class="xyz"><?php echo nl2br($variable_con_el_texto);?></div>
```